# CSS responsive % height

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm trying to make a grid of `div`s with `position: absolute` scale responsively.

When the viewport of the demo is `1100px` (viewable by clicking `Full Page` in the demo below) the vertical and horizontal spacing between the `<div><img></div>` is equal.

However, when the viewport width changes to `850px` and below, the vertical spacing increases faster than the horizontal spacing.

I've calculated the `#entn`'s `top:`  `%` value based on the `%` height of `height: 875px;`. However, this does not scale as the viewport width decreases.

Help appreciated.

```css
    #enterprise-gallery {width: 1259px; height: 875px; max-width: 100%; position: relative; margin: auto;}
    #enterprise-gallery div {position: absolute;}
    #enterprise-gallery div img {border-radius: 26px; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
    @media (max-width: 1330px) {
        #enterprise-gallery {
            height: 875px; 
            width: 885px; 
            max-width: 100%;
        }
        #ent1 {width: 33.45% !important;}
        #ent2 {width: 38.31% !important; left: 36.05% !important;}
        #ent3 {width: 23.05% !important;}
        #ent4 {width: 42.82% !important; top: 24% !important;}
        #ent5 {width: 28.36% !important; left: 45.42% !important; top: 24% !important;}
        #ent6 {width: 38.98% !important; top: 48.5% !important;}
        #ent7 {width: 32.66% !important; left: 41.59% !important; top: 48.5% !important;}
        #ent8 {width: 23.05% !important; top: 39% !important;}
    }
```

```html
    <div id="enterprise-gallery">
      <div style="width: 422px; left: 0; top: 0;" id="ent1"><img src="https://mandoemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/Mandoe-Enterprise-7.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" alt=""/></div>
      <div style="width: 483px; left: 454px; top: 0;" id="ent2"><img src="https://mandoemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/Mandoe-Enterprise-6.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" alt=""/></div>
      <div style="width: 290px; right: 0; top: 0;" id="ent3"><img src="https://mandoemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/Mandoe-Enterprise-8.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" alt=""/></div>
      <div style="width: 540px; left: 0; top: 296px" id="ent4"><img src="https://mandoemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/Mandoe-Enterprise-4.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" alt=""/></div>
      <div style="width: 358px; left: 576px; top: 296px;" id="ent5"><img src="https://mandoemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/Mandoe-Enterprise-2.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" alt=""/></div>
      <div style="width: 491px; left: 0; top: 591px;" id="ent6"><img src="https://mandoemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/Mandoe-Enterprise-3.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" alt=""/></div>
      <div style="width: 412px; left: 525px; top: 591px;" id="ent7"><img src="https://mandoemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/Mandoe-Enterprise-5-1.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" alt=""/></div>
      <div style="width: 288px; right: 0; top: 482px;" id="ent8"><img src="https://mandoemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/Mandoe-Enterprise-1.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" alt=""/></div>
    </div>
```

**EDIT**

I've tried using CSS Grid with the following code generated from https://grid.layoutit.com/, but not quite getting there.

```
<style>
    #enterprise-gallery {
      width: 1259px;
      max-width: 90%;
      margin: auto;
      display: grid; 
      grid-template-columns: 33.45% 38.31% 23.05%; 
      grid-template-rows: 30.78% 30.78% 30.78%; 
      gap: 2.6% 2.6%; 
      grid-template-areas: 
        "a a b"
        "a a b"
        "c c b"
        "c c d"
        "e e d"
        "e e d";
    }
    #enterprise-gallery div img {border-radius: 26px;}
</style>
<div id="enterprise-gallery">
  <div><img src="https://mandoemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/Mandoe-Enterprise-7.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" alt=""/></div>
  <div><img src="https://mandoemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/Mandoe-Enterprise-6.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" alt=""/></div>
  <div><img src="https://mandoemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/Mandoe-Enterprise-8.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" alt=""/></div>
  <div><img src="https://mandoemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/Mandoe-Enterprise-4.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" alt=""/></div>
  <div><img src="https://mandoemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/Mandoe-Enterprise-2.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" alt=""/></div>
  <div><img src="https://mandoemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/Mandoe-Enterprise-3.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" alt=""/></div>
  <div><img src="https://mandoemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/Mandoe-Enterprise-5-1.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" alt=""/></div>
  <div><img src="https://mandoemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/Mandoe-Enterprise-1.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" alt=""/></div>
</div>
```

**EDIT2**

The code from **Ghanshyam Patel** solved the tablet problem beautifully.

On mobile, I can't get the `top` figure unset, so all `#entn` `div`s stack on top of each other.

```
@media (max-width: 470px) {
  #enterprise-gallery {
    height: 300vh;
    width: calc(100vw - 60px);
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  #ent1 {
    width: 100% !important;
    top: unset !important;
  }
  #ent2 {
    width: 100% !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    top: unset !important;
  }
  #ent3 {
    width: 100% !important;
    top: unset !important;
  }
  #ent4 {
    width: 100% !important;
    top: unset !important;
  }
  #ent5 {
    width: 100% !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    top: unset !important;
  }
  #ent6 {
    width: 100% !important;
    top: unset !important;
  }
  #ent7 {
    width: 100% !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    top: unset !important;
  }
  #ent8 {
    width: 100% !important;
    top: unset !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: You are bound to get lots of vertical spacing when the height is fixed but the images are smaller. Have you considered laying this out with a CSS grid rather than trying to position everything 'by hand'?

Comment: CSS grid would be the easiest solution if masonry layout isn't critical. In case staggered, masonry look is a requirement and image ordering isn't critical, CSS `columns` could be an alternative. If you have to keep a specific order of the images while masonry, you'd have a better luck with a sprinkle of JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the grid CSS, but in a grid layout, you can merge the row or columns. So you can't achieve the same result as your aspect.

I have added a CSS solution for you. Just used "calc" CSS function. please check. I think this is what you need. Feel free to comment if you have any questions.

```css
#enterprise-gallery {
  width: 1259px;
  height: 100vw;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

#enterprise-gallery div {
  position: absolute;
}

#enterprise-gallery div img {
  border-radius: 26px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 1330px) {
  #enterprise-gallery {
    height: calc(100vw - 100px);
    width: calc(100vw - 100px);
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  #ent1 {
    width: 33.45% !important;
  }
  #ent2 {
    width: 38.31% !important;
    left: 36.05% !important;
  }
  #ent3 {
    width: 23.05% !important;
  }
  #ent4 {
    width: 42.82% !important;
    top: 24% !important;
  }
  #ent5 {
    width: 28.36% !important;
    left: 45.42% !important;
    top: 24% !important;
  }
  #ent6 {
    width: 38.98% !important;
    top: 48.5% !important;
  }
  #ent7 {
    width: 32.66% !important;
    left: 41.59% !important;
    top: 48.5% !important;
  }
  #ent8 {
    width: 23.05% !important;
    top: 39% !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="enterprise-gallery">
  <div style="width: 422px; left: 0; top: 0;" id="ent1"><img src="https://mandoemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/Mandoe-Enterprise-7.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" alt="" /></div>
  <div style="width: 483px; left: 454px; top: 0;" id="ent2"><img src="https://mandoemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/Mandoe-Enterprise-6.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" alt="" /></div>
  <div style="width: 290px; right: 0; top: 0;" id="ent3"><img src="https://mandoemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/Mandoe-Enterprise-8.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" alt="" /></div>
  <div style="width: 540px; left: 0; top: 296px" id="ent4"><img src="https://mandoemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/Mandoe-Enterprise-4.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" alt="" /></div>
  <div style="width: 358px; left: 576px; top: 296px;" id="ent5"><img src="https://mandoemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/Mandoe-Enterprise-2.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" alt="" /></div>
  <div style="width: 491px; left: 0; top: 591px;" id="ent6"><img src="https://mandoemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/Mandoe-Enterprise-3.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" alt="" /></div>
  <div style="width: 412px; left: 525px; top: 591px;" id="ent7"><img src="https://mandoemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/Mandoe-Enterprise-5-1.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" alt="" /></div>
  <div style="width: 288px; right: 0; top: 482px;" id="ent8"><img src="https://mandoemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/Mandoe-Enterprise-1.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" alt="" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks beautiful, Ghanshyam. Do you mean `you can't merge the row or columns` instead of `you can merge the row or columns`?

Comment: You can merge the row and columns, but in a table format, so you can't achieve the same design as you need. Thank you!!